# getting error in laravel related with create input to model

Tags: laravel

im beginner in laravel and im trying to figure out whats wrong with the code, i have tried to pass the  $userr into integer, but found different difficulties. Here is the error im getting :

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":5}]'           for column 'userid' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `objectsaccess` (`userid`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ([{"id":5}], 2017-03-21 23:11:12, 2017-03-21 23:11:12))

the model code :

```
   $userr = User::select('users.id')
        ->where(['remember_token' => $token])

        ->get();

    $objectt = Object::select('objects.id')
        ->where(['objects.name' => $passname])
        ->get();

    $inputs = [  'userid' => $userr,'objectid' => $objectt];

    ObjectAccess::create($inputs);
```

i want to create a new row with userid and object id inside objectsaccess. but had no success.

Any idea why is this?

thank you!

EDIT 1 :

fixed first problem but im getting error :

> ErrorException in Collection.php line 1440:
>   Undefined offset: 0
>   in Collection.php line 1440
>   at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined offset: 0', '/var/www/html/rx1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php', 1440, array('key' => 0)) in Collection.php line 1440
>   at Collection->offsetGet(0) in Object.php line 140

```
    if($object)
    {


        $return['errors'] = 'Send Successful';

        $return['status'] = 200;
        $return['success'] = 1;
        $return['content'] = $object['0']->content; // this is line 140  of object.php
        $return['ylink'] = $object['0']->ylink;
        $return['slink'] = $object['0']->slink;
        return $return;
    }
```

EDIT 2  ($object ):

```
$object = Object::select('objects.*', 'users.LAST','users.remember_token')
        ->join('users', 'users.LAST', '=', 'objects.passvariable')
       ->where(['remember_token' => $token])
        //->where('objects.passvariable', 'users.passvariable')
        ->where(['objects.name' => $passname])
        ->get();
```

Comment: You're passing an object for the id instead of an integer. `$inputs = [  'userid' => $userr->id,'objectid' => $objectt->id];` Also you should look into using Eloquent relationships for this.

Comment: im getting 
ErrorException in Collection.php line 1440:
Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the refine your code first. Maybe use Relationships as mentioned in the comment. But first fix your query like this.

```
 $userr = User::select('id')
 ->where('remember_token', $token)
 ->first(); //<-- replace get()
```

Because `get()` returns a collection and first returns an object. Same applies to `$objectt`.

Then your SQL only considered `userid` and ignored `objectid`. Perhaps, you did not add `objectid` in your `$fillable` array of `ObjectAccess`

At the end you can simply do

```
ObjectAccess::create([
    'userid' => $userr->id,
    'objectid' => $objectt->id
]);
```

**Edit**

Since your `$object` variable is actually a collection, do it like this.

```
if ( $object ) {
    $return['errors'] = 'Send Successful';
    $return['status'] = 200;
    $return['success'] = 1;
    $first = $object->first();

    if ( $first ) {
        $return['content'] = $first->content;
        $return['ylink']   = $first->ylink;
        $return['slink']   = $first->slink;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Just as a convention, name your collection/array variable with `s` at the end so you or any other developer will know it's plural so it's either a collection or an array.

Comment: hello, i have tried the code as such, but gettign next error :                                                                          ErrorException in Collection.php line 1440:
Undefined offset: 0

Comment: I think this code fixed your original error asked in this question. The error you have receiving now comes from somewhere else as I am not playing with collection. Can you post all the code in that function? Update your question and post all the code in your function. Somewhere you are playing with a collect/array and receiving that error.

Comment: Please, mark my answer since I solved your initial issue. Every other issue arising has nothing to do with your initial question, but I'm happy to help. Check my edit1

Comment: Refresh the page.

Comment: $object is different than $objectt

Comment: You see? that's why I said put all your code there. You are just making stuff difficult for both of us by not providing code.

Comment: Are you trying to get a collection or a single item. If you want a single item, use `first()` instead of `get()`. If you expect a collection, then I show you how to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want a collection, because im getting $object['0']->content, $object['0']->ylink. etc

Comment: i did the changes, but im getting 
ErrorException in Object.php line 140:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Check again. I added a check to make sure there is actually something inside the collection with `if ( $first ) {}`

Comment: gettign this error : QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'objectid' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `objectsaccess` (`userid`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (5, 2017-03-22 01:33:03, 2017-03-22 01:33:03))

Comment: Now this is a different error. Because you didn't follow my first instruction when I said add `objectid` in the `$fillable` array of your `ObjectAccess` model. `protected $fillabale = ['userid', 'objectid'];`. Then pass both objectid and userid to the create method the way I did.

Comment: it gets userid and objectid right (5 and 25) but it gives this error : MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 225:
in Model.php line 225
at Model->fill(array('userid' => 5, 'objectid' => 25)) in Model.php line 145

Comment: you had a misspelt protected $fillabale = ['userid', 'objectid']; $fillable

Comment: Well, you could upvote my answer for the extra help. Only if you want. Not a requirement.

Comment: it said upvotes with lass then 15 rep are recorded but not shown, but i did